# Including ioctl codes in userspace program

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

Is there is a common practice for userspace programs to include `ioctl` codes used in a kernel module.

**mydev.h**:

```
#ifndef MYDEV_H
#define MYDEV_H

#define <linux/ioctl.h>

#define MYDEV_IOC_MAGIC 'C'

#define MYDEV_IOC_FOO   _IO(MYDEV_IOC_MAGIC, 0)
#define MYDEV_IOC_BAR   _IOW(MYDEV_IOC_MAGIC, 1, int)

#endif
```

I typically put my `ioctl` codes in a header which I include in my kernel module code. I considered just including this header in my userspace applications, but I realized that the **linux/ioctl.h** file path may not exist on most systems (e.g. systems with no exported kernel headers).

The solution seems to be to change the include line to: `#include <sys/ioctl.h>`; but then I couldn't use this header for my kernel module.

Is there a better solution to this problem, or is it common to have two separate but nearly identical header files?

Comment: If you're concerned about maintenance, you could just automatically generate a userland header from your kernel header when building your module.

Comment: Is there a way to evaluate a preprocessor macro and print it to a file with GCC's preprocessor?

Comment: If not, is it usual to write a standalone C program that generates the userland header by passing the defines to a printf; or is there another preferred method?

Comment: There is the `-E` flag.  I'm not sure if that's exactly what you mean.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to compile a C program which includes `stdio.h` (for generating the file) as well as the Linux kernel headers (for evaluating the ioctl macros).

Comment: I don't think you should be *including* the kernel header.  It should be the *input* to your conversion program.

Comment: @VilhelmGray In which directory did you add the ioctl header file that needs to be shared between kernel and user program?

Comment: @sagargurtu I ended up using <sys/ioctl.h> in userspace, and <linux/ioctl.h> in kernelspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could leverage the **_*KERNEL*_** macro.

```
#ifdef __KERNEL__
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#else
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#endif
```

You may have to abstract the actual ioctl values too, but you get the idea.